# ORA-00942 error while granting execution rights

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I want to add partitions to an existing table. Therefore I followed this [example.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_redefinition_example.htm)

When trying to:

```
grant execute on dbms_redefinition to USER
```

Oracle returns the following error:

```
Error starting at line 13 in command:
grant execute on dbms_redefinition to USER
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: What user did you log in with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to be logged in as SYSDBA to grant a user execute rights on that package.

Second, be aware that for dbms_redefinition to work the user also requires the following rights:

```
ALTER ANY TABLE
CREATE ANY TABLE
DROP ANY TABLE
LOCK ANY TABLE
SELECT ANY TABLE
```

And, depending on the target table you might also need:

```
CREATE ANY INDEX
CREATE ANY TRIGGER
```

Those are VERY powerful rights to be granted to a user, so you might want to revoke them after doing what needs to be done. Another good example for using this package [is here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/4)

Comment: True, the DBA just fixed that for me! Thanks alot anyway!